# Java: Is it OK to use String constant or interned String for locked object in multi-threading?

Tags: java, multithreading

code snippet is like below:

```
Map<Class<?>, ConcurrentHashMap<String, T>> m;
...
...
map = m.get(clazz);
if(map.get(param) == null){
  String str = clazz.getSimpleName()+param;
  String internedStr = str.intern();
  synchronized(internedStr){
     if(map.get(param) == null){
     ... // time-consuming task
        map.put(param, someValue);
     }
  }
}
```

basically, I want to just lock on internedStr(which is immutable) so that when other threads **meet the same condition(clazz, param)**, it waits for the lock.

Are there any problems with such a solution?

Comment: string class is developed so that their objects are inmutable...

Comment: I'd say the biggest problem is that it's unclear. Can you explain what you're trying to do in a broader sense?

Comment: Why not just synchronize on the class object?

Comment: @chrylis The sync is being done on class name + param.

Comment: @chrylis  I want to lock as small as possible

Comment: Are you working with Java 8?

Comment: Why do you think it wouldn't work?

Comment: @Kayaman yes, but intern() means `==`, so it has nothing to do with the version.

Comment: @matt I think it works, I'm just afraid there are some hidden problems.

Comment: I asked you for the version, not how `intern()` works.

Comment: @Kayaman yes, java 8

Comment: From the looks of it, why not just use `map` as your object to synchronize on? Although, Kayaman's solution appears to be a better answer.

Comment: @matt Because the goal is to get the locking on as small a portion as possible, i.e. the class and the parameter. Since you can't do a `synchronized(map, param)` the code in question attempts to hack around by combining the names and interning it, giving the fine grained lock object. However, using `synchronized` should be the last effort these days, when you have `java.util.concurrent` full of pretty and efficient synch primitives.

Comment: One reason why it's not OK to use interned string as lock object: if you started doing that here in that component, what would happen if another component elsewhere in your application decided to also use this string construct (class name + param) to use as intrinsic lock? (+1 for @Kayaman's answer)

Comment: Re, "the goal is to get the locking on as small a portion as possible..."  Don't do that for a generic `Map`!!  The contract for `Map` does _not_ require an implementation to be thread safe.  You can't assume it's safe for one thread to call `m.get(k)` or `m.put(k, v)` while some other thread thread calls `m.put(k′, v′)`.

Comment: @jameslarge That's why my answer states as the first thing to use `ConcurrentMap`.

Comment: @Kayaman, Your answer provides the OP with an example that is (a) correct, and (b) much cleaner than the original, but as folks around here like to say, StackOverflow is not [just] a code writing service. I thought that the OP might want to know that her original snippet actually is _unsafe_: It allows one thread to call `map.put(k,v)` while another thread simultaneously accesses the same `map` using a different key.  There are some `Map` implementations (e.g., `ConcurrentHashMap`) that allow you to do that, but _in general_ you can't make that assumption.

Comment: @jameslarge Well you're certainly right about that. The original code was already going down a bad direction, so I didn't want to speculate on (unseen) code that would take it to an even worse direction :)

Comment: @Kayaman the inner map is concurrentHashMap, then are there problems?

Comment: @Lily There can always be problems since I don't know what kind of other code you intend to write, but at least now you have a thread-safe concurrent collection as the inner one which eliminates some of the potential problems with your original code. Did you write the original code yourself?

Comment: @Kayaman what `original code` do you mean?

Comment: The one in your question of course.

Comment: @Kayaman yes, it is.

Comment: Okay then. Well is there anything unclear to you still, or are you happy with my answer?

Answer (score 6):

`ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent()` to the rescue. For this you need to make sure that your inner maps are `ConcurrentHashMaps` so it's threadsafe. However, it makes the code a *lot* simpler: you get rid of `intern()`, you get rid of double checked locking, and you get rid of `synchronized`. Not to mention the code reads a lot better.

```
Map<Class<?>, ConcurrentHashMap<String, T>> m;
...
map = m.get(clazz);
Result r = map.computeIfAbsent(param, key -> {
    // Perform time consuming task
    return result;
});
```

The inner map will be locked only for the specified `param`, and the computation will be done only once. Using a higher level concurrent mechanism beats hand made synchronization 1-0 here. The inner maps also won't affect the locking of any of the other inner maps.

If you intend to *modify* the maps from other places than this, you need to pay further attention to what might be happening to the map at the same time (mainly that a calculation might be ongoing). However that's a lot easier to handle than with your original code.

Comment: Isn't this answer similar to synchronizing on `map` from ops question? Also if you check the docs: "Some attempted update operations on this map by other threads may be blocked while computation is in progress, so the computation should be short and simple"

Comment: No, it's not similar syncing on the map locks the whole map. This is similar to synchronizing on `param` but without it affecting other inner maps with the same `param` (i.e. basically `synchronized(map, param)`. As for potential updates (I doubt there are any), it would block them yes, which is a good thing. The original code would allow lost updates (unless they do the whole intern-sync thing).

Comment: It's going to block updates to the map, and which ones it isn't clear. Which is similar synchronizing on `map`. In terms of the 'size of the lock' I would say `map` > ConcurrentHashMap > internedString. As for usability, I would say your method is better.

Comment: You're wrong. If you sync on `map`, it blocks operations for all `params`. My method blocks operations only for the single `param`. Which is exactly what the author was looking for. This is the version of the code in the question which doesn't do hacks.

Comment: It only blocks operations for all params on that specific map, *when they're in another synchronized block*. Also you have not addressed this issue where the docs specifically say, "short and simple".

Comment: Well, it would be quite foolish to modify the map in a synch block from one point and not from another. That's a great way to get race conditions and other concurrency issues. As for the short and simple, it doesn't apply here. We're not interested in modifying the map from elsewhere, we're lazily loading a value that requires a heavy operation (basically a cache).

Comment: what if `map.computeIfAbsent(param, key -> { do long-time job;
    map.put(key, value);   
    return result;
});`  I mean, there is `map.put(key, value);   `

Comment: @Lily When you return `result` it gets associated to the key so there's no need for an additional `put`.

Comment: @Kayaman you mean the pair <param, result> is automatically put into the map?

Comment: @Lily Well yes, `param` is your key. The `computeIfAbsent()` method either returns the value associated with the key (`param`), or it computes the value (possibly using the key for the computation) and returns it, and associates it with the key.

Answer (score -1):

You can use any simple object like final Object lock= new Object(); as well make sure you mark the reference as final .

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.